# How to create chart bar with lines in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bar-chart

I want create some Chart Bar + line, but i dont know how to combine two chart.

I wannt make Like this pic Bar
[image]

Thanks, Hope someone can Help my problem

Comment: Use charting library like this https://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes

Comment: This seems like another good place to look: https://canvasjs.com/jquery-charts/column-line-area-chart/

Comment: Google "js chart"

Answer (score 1):

How about this one https://jsfiddle.net/nu7cx100/

```js
window.onload = function () {
     var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{              
      title:{
       text: "Grafik Riwayat PKPT"
      },
      axisX:{
       valueFormatString: "####",
       interval: 1
      },
      axisY:[{
       title: "Linear Scale",
       lineColor: "#369EAD",
       titleFontColor: "#369EAD",
       labelFontColor: "#369EAD"
      }],
      axisY2:[{
       title: "Linear Scale",
       lineColor: "#7F6084",
       titleFontColor: "#7F6084",
       labelFontColor: "#7F6084"
      }],
    
     data: [
     {
      type: "column",
      showInLegend: true,
      //axisYIndex: 0, //Defaults to Zero
      name: "ANNGGARAN",
      xValueFormatString: "####",
      dataPoints: [
       { x: 2006, y: 60 },
       { x: 2007, y: 20 },
       { x: 2008, y: 50 },
       { x: 2009, y: 70 },
       { x: 2010, y: 10 },
       { x: 2011, y: 50 },
       { x: 2012, y: 50 },
       { x: 2013, y: 20 },
       { x: 2014, y: 20 }
      ]
     },
     {
      type: "line",
      showInLegend: true,
      axisYIndex: 1, //Defaults to Zero
      name: "KEGIATAN",
      xValueFormatString: "####",
      dataPoints: [
       { x: 2006, y: 15 },
       { x: 2007, y: 3 },
       { x: 2008, y: 20 },
       { x: 2009, y: 10 },
       { x: 2010, y: 15 },
       { x: 2011, y: 10 },
       { x: 2012, y: 20 },
       { x: 2013, y: 20 },
       { x: 2014, y: 2 }
      ]
     }
     ]
     });
    
     chart.render();
    }
```

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery.canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

It uses canvasjs
Hope this helps